# Difference between TypeScript and TypeScript SDK

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript.  Can anyone tell me what is the difference between TypeScript and TypeScript SDK.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

An SDK (Software Development Kit) is a tool that helps you to develop in a certain language. Typescript is the language which has its syntax while a TypeScript SDK are the tools (like Syntax highlighting, etc.) that you need to develop in a certain IDE (like VS Code, etc.)

Comment: Thank you that helps clarify a lot of things :-)